# Maven : Is it possible to bundle generated artifact from sibling module in a zip file?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, maven-assembly-plugin

```
root
  |-- core-module1
               |-- target/hibernate3/
  |-- assembly-module
               |-- src/main/resources
  |-- pom.xml
```

We would like to bundle ddl file generated in core-module's target/hibernate3 using hbm2ddl goal from hibernate3-maven-plugin plugin in assembly-module. We are exploring maven-assembly-plugin using moduleSets but haven't had much luck for well over 3 hours now.

Does anyone know if its even possible or would anyone like to take a look at our pom files?

> Brief Question : Is it even possible to generate a zip file with
>   content from sibling modules?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. First question, why are those ddl not generated as resources then?

Comment: Well, I have generated resource and bundled it in a zip file. But this bundle would not get pushed to Nexus repository manager.